# TypeError: must be str, not ValueError using Boruta

Tags: python

I'm trying to do feature extraction for my data which contains around 5K attributes & I have no.of records around 4.5K. I'm trying to do feature engineering to reduce variables using python 3.x.
Pandas data frame,df, contains my raw data.So I used following code

```
x=df.drop(['ID','target'],axis=1).values
y=df['target'].values
rfc=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200,n_jobs=4,class_weight='balanced',max_depth=6)  
boruta_selector=BorutaPy(rfc,n_estimators='auto',verbose=2)
boruta_selector.fit(x,y)
```

But I'm getting error message as TypeError: must be str, not ValueError
I did a close inspection of my data & couldn't find any Valueerror. All of my attribute contains numerical value. Can you please help me to solve this issue

Below is the error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-80afa99c8401>", line 1, in <module>
    boruta_selector.fit(x,y)

  File "C:\Users\ChristinaHughes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boruta\boruta_py.py", line 201, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\ChristinaHughes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boruta\boruta_py.py", line 285, in _fit
    cur_imp = self._add_shadows_get_imps(X, y, dec_reg)

  File "C:\Users\ChristinaHughes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boruta\boruta_py.py", line 408, in _add_shadows_get_imps
    imp = self._get_imp(np.hstack((x_cur, x_sha)), y)

  File "C:\Users\ChristinaHughes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boruta\boruta_py.py", line 383, in _get_imp
    'estimator cannot be fitted to your data.\n' + e)

TypeError: must be str, not ValueError
```

I also have updated my boruta package. Please refer attached screenshot.But still I got same error
[image]

Comment: What are `type(x)` and `type(y)`? Also, what is `type(boruta_selector)`?

Comment: Update your Boruta installation.  Note that in the most recent version on github this error has been fixed: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py/blob/master/boruta/boruta_py.py#L383

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @PatrickHaugh. I installed boruta today only. Are you asking me to run this command `pip install Boruta -U`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh. I have updated the Boruta using pip,refer the screen shot in my first post, but got same error. I also tried one more thing,replace my older boruta_py.py with the one in github. But no improvement.

Comment: @ChristinaHughes I have used Boruta a lot of times successfully. Can you add your data and full code?

Comment: @Joel, type(x) and type(y) are numpy.ndarray & type(boruta_selector) is boruta.boruta_py.BorutaPy

Comment: can you add the data ?